# Audit Tracking but wont save

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the below code to track changes on a form and it works fine.

However, I am trying to use it on my main form to record just the date/time that someone clicks a button However I get the following error:

> You entered an expression that has no value

The debug takes me to this:

```
 rs!PriorInfo = Screen.ActiveControl.OldValue
```

My code

```
Function TrackChanges()
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strCtl As String
 Dim strReason As String

 ' strReason = InputBox("Reason For Changes")
 strCtl = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
 strSQL = "SELECT Audit.* FROM Audit;"

 Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)


 If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then rs.MoveLast

 With rs
 .AddNew
rs!FormName = Screen.ActiveForm
 rs!ControlName = strCtl
 rs!DateChanged = Date
 rs!TimeChanged = Time()
 rs!PriorInfo = Screen.ActiveControl.OldValue
 rs!NewInfo = Screen.ActiveControl.Value
 rs!CurrentUser = fOSUserName
' rs!Reason = strReason
 .Update
 End With

 Set db = Nothing
 Set rs = Nothing
 End Function
```

I assume I need to tell it to accept null values but unsure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nz(Screen.ActiveControl.OldValue)` will return an empty string instead of a null value.

`Nz(Screen.ActiveControl.OldValue,"<Null>")` if PriorInfo is text and you want to record it was null.

`Nz(Screen.ActiveControl.OldValue,-1)` if PriorInfo is numeric and -1 is a safe "null" number.